# Rendering a Fragment in React Native App produces no UI output

Tags: android, react-native, android-fragments

I am following a guide that integrates a Fragment into a react native app. It initiates it in the following way.

```
  componentDidMount(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.findId();
    }, 400);
  }

  findId = () => {
    const androidViewId = findNodeHandle(this.androidFragment);
    UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
      androidViewId,
      UIManager.GoogleNavigationView.Commands.create.toString(),
      [androidViewId]
    );
  };
```

The manager that exposes this via `requireNativeComponent` does the following

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected FrameLayout createViewInstance(@NonNull ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
          return new FrameLayout(reactContext);
    }
```

```
    @Override
    public void receiveCommand(@NonNull FrameLayout root, String commandId, @Nullable ReadableArray args) {
        super.receiveCommand(root, commandId,args);
        int reactNativeViewId = args.getInt(0);
        int commandIdInt = Integer.parseInt(commandId);

        switch(commandIdInt) {
            case COMMAND_CREATE:
                createFragment(root, reactNativeViewId);
                break;
            default: {

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean needsCustomLayoutForChildren() {
        return true;
    }

    public void createFragment(FrameLayout parentLayout, int reactNativeViewId) {
        final GoogleNavigationFragment myFrag = new GoogleNavigationFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = ((FragmentActivity) this.context.getCurrentActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(reactNativeViewId, myFrag);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

And the Fragment itself:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("TZ", "GOING TO INFLATE");

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_navigation, container, false);
    }
```

```
XML: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/light_blue_600"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.Wheelzv3.FullscreenContainer"
    tools:context=".GoogleNavigationFragment">
    <Button android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="smart" />

    <!-- <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.navigation.SupportNavigationFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> -->
</FrameLayout>
```

I am not seeing any UI in react native as a result of this.